# Iterate over column names in an R data frame in order to change their type

Tags: r

```
library(lubridate)

# data to build the df
d1 <- c("1/2/14", "3/5/15", "1/13/11") #start
d2 <- c("1/2/15", "4/5/15", "6/18/15") #stop
d3 <- c("5/16/08", "1/7/07", "6/22/01") #start
d4 <- c("11/29/12", "8/5/14", "1/13/12") #stop
a <- c("Blah", "Blah", "Blah")
b <- c("Blah", "Blah", "Blah")
c <- c("Blah", "Blah", "Blah")
f <- c("Blah", "Blah", "Blah")
colNames <- c("Col.a", "Col.b", "Col.c", "Project1.start", "Project1.end", "Project2.start", "Project2.end", "Col.f")

# assemble the df
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d1,d2,d3,d4,f)
names(df) <- colNames

# change the char cols for dX into POSIX date objects to play nicely with    
# lubridate
df$Project1.start <- mdy(df$Project1.start)
df$Project1.end <- mdy(df$Project1.end)
df$Project2.start <- mdy(df$Project2.start)
df$Project2.end <- mdy(df$Project2.end)
```

BUT! I want to do the above `mdy` iteratively over the dX that I specify.
Imagine that instead of d1-d4 I have d1-d142. There must be an elegant,
i.e., non-brute force way of doing this!

so, I tried this. I know that I'm doing `mdy` on too many columns, but I am just trying to make it work at all. I've tried for loops with `seq()`, etc., but I know
that I'm missing the vector based approach that R expects.

```
f <- function(x) {x <- mdy(x)}
newdf <- apply(df,2,f)
```

but it throws

```
Warning messages:
1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
...
10: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

and the newdf is bad:

```
     Col.a Col.b Col.c Project1.start Project1.end Project2.start Project2.end Col.f
[1,]    NA    NA    NA             NA           NA             NA           NA    NA
[2,]    NA    NA    NA             NA           NA             NA           NA    NA
[3,]    NA    NA    NA             NA           NA             NA           NA    NA

       Project1.duration Project2.duration
[1,]                NA                NA
[2,]                NA                NA
[3,]                NA                NA
```

What am I doing that is just so st00pid?

So, once that is done, we want to do some date math

```
df$Project1.duration <- (df$Project1.end - df$Project1.start )
df$Project2.duration <- (df$Project2.end - df$Project2.start )
```

same here. I want to be able to iterate over all the durations for all the dX columns but perhaps I need to reshape the data to make this happen. How would you take this large number of durations for all of these different projects that are separately coded and reassemble them into a df so that I can make a plot of the different durations for each project. In my sample df I have three different durations, rows 1:3, to be able to compare the rows for each project.

Comment: Something like this: `for (col in 1:10) df[col] <- mdy(df[col])` ?

Comment: Yep, that is what I was trying, even with `seq()` to make it pretty. but it throws the 3: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. and I get NA for everything in newdf using for (col in 4:7){
    newdf[col] <- mdy(df[col])
}

Comment: don't use `apply`, it converts the object to a matrix which doesn't handle mixed types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is because your `apply` is applying `mdy` to *every* column of `df`, not just the "ProjectX.{start,end}" ones. And also because `df[col]` is a `data.frame`, and `mdy` needs a vector -- try `df[[col]]`.

e.g.

```
cols <- grep('Project', names(df))
# do a one-liner like this
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], mdy)
# or a loop like this if you want
for (col in cols) {
    df[[col]] <- mdy(df[[col]])
}
```

In regards to calculating per-project data (like duration), you can kludge it like this:

```
projects <- paste0('Project', 1:2) # however many projects
df[paste0(projects, '.duration')] <- df[paste0(projects, '.end')] - df[paste0(projects, '.start')]
```

---

However in the long run (particularly if you have lots of projects or want to calculate lots of stats per project, not just duration) you might consider having your data in long format, i.e.

```
Project  start  end duration
 1       ...
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
```

(probably with some sort of ID variable so you know which project 2 went with which project 1)

Then you can easily do `mydf$duration <- mydf$end - mydf$start` and if you want it in wide format again you can make use of `reshape`.